# How login using PhantomJS with SSO authentication and certifications together?

Tags: javascript, certificate, phantomjs, single-sign-on

I am trying to navigate into a corporate website using **PhantomJS**. The problem is that the login is only allowed through **SSO (Single sign-on)** and a **certification**.

How could I use PhantomJS, SSO authentication and certifications together?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, hope I find some help in here :)